# Reflection in multiple wrapped objects

Tags: java, reflection, junit, mockito, transactional

In a JUnit test, I want to change the hibernate template in a Spring DAO. This DAO is

1. annotated with @Transactional so it gets wrapped during runtime and
2. spyed upon by Mockitos spy()- method. So the DAO will be wrapped a second time by that spy.

So the DAO now has two wrapping objects: One from @Transactional, one from the spy. Due to the fact that it's not known which of those wrapper is created first, I can't set the hibernate template in the DAO via reflection.

How can I set the template in the doubled-wrapped DAO?

[Edit]

Some Source:

```
/**
* This class gets wrapped by a proxy object because of @Transactional.
*/
@Transactional 
public class MyDao implements SomeDaoInterface { ... }
```

In a test class:

```
public class MyTestClass {
@Autowired 
private MyDao myDao;

@Test
public void myTestMethod() throws Exception {
   final MyDao daoSpy = spy(myDao);   // Dao gets wrapped with second wrapper

   final Field field = MyDao.class.getDeclaredField("template");
   field.setAccessible(true);
   field.set(daoSpy, mySpecialMockedTemplate);  // ERROR: want to inject the template but
                                                // dont know in which wrapper
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you add some sample code ?

Answer (score 2):

Call the setter method instead of accessing the field.

Comment: Using a setter is not solving the problem: Spring wrappes the dao because of @Autowired. The setter will set any given property into this wrap, not the dao.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you reflection code is wrong. Use this statement instead :

```
field.set(daoSpy, mySpecialMockedTemplate);
```

However looking at your test code, it seems you are using Spring to create the `MyDao` instance. It seems kind of weird to use reflection to set the template, why not configure it in Spring ?
Or even use an actual setter ? Or make the field protected, so only the unit test can access it.

EDIT : About injection, you could create the DAO instance in your test and have your `specialMockedTemplate` injected by Mockito. You could writ something like :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTestClass {
    @InjectMocks private MyDao dao;

    @Mock SpecialTemplate specialTemplate;

    @Test void dao_should_call_the_template_with_parameter_A_and_B() {
        // given

        // when
        dao.someCall("A", "B");

        // then
        verify(specialTemplate).someCallWith("A", "B");
    }
}
```

A few warnings though, avoid partial mocking if possible (using spies). Avoid moking types you don't own, you should read this [blog post entry](http://www.davesquared.net/2011/04/dont-mock-types-you-dont-own.html) why this is a bad idea.

Comment: PowerMockito might help here, for yet another option.

Comment: While the PowerMock lib is great for code difficult to test, I would strongly recommand to avoid design code that need Powermock to be tested. It's the road to hacks and code/test difficult to maintain.

Comment: Right, I postet a wrong reflection code. Using a setter is not solving the problem: Spring wrappes the dao because of @Autowired. The setter will set any given property into this wrap, not the dao. Configuring in Spring actually seems to be the only way to do this. Alternatively the dao could get instanciated instead of autowired.

Comment: Mockito offers a light auto-injection utility, I edited my answer in this regard.